# Android ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail with no Size specified is deprecated in API level 29

Tags: java, android

```
public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (String filePath, 
                int kind)
```

The above method is deprecated in `API` level 29.

We are required to use this now:

```
public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (File file, 
                Size size, 
                CancellationSignal signal)
```

My question is **how can I set the `Size` to be the native size of the video `File` that I am creating the thumbnail from**?

**I want it to be the same `height/width and dimensions`**.

Before, I could just use
`ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file_path, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND)`;

Answer (score 0):

Use MediaMetadataRetriever class to get the size. Size will be equal to the size of video file created.

```
public static Size getThumbSize(String path) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever dataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    dataRetriever.setDataSource(path);
    String width = 
    dataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
    String height = 
    dataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
    return new Size(Integer.parseInt(width), Integer.parseInt(height));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
            val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
            retriever.setDataSource(context, uri)
            val bitmap = retriever.frameAtTime
            viewBinding.yourImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            retriever.release()
            bitmap?.recycle()
```